# How to parse JSON datetime string in symfony2 so it can be persisted with doctrine

Tags: php, json, symfony, date, doctrine

I'm looking for a way to convert a date from a json feed (i am unable to change how the date is passed in the feed)

The date is passed as a string

```
'BirthDate' => string '/Date(610776000000-0400)/' (length=25)
```

How do i parse this to a date that i can persist with doctrine?
(BirthDate is set-up as a datetime field)

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $thingyRepo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Thingy');

    $entry = new Thingy();
    $entry->setBirthDate(this->parseDate($myData['BirthDate']));
    $em->persist($entry);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: looks like a timestamp (in Milliseconds) with timezone offset
grep the nummeric part, then you may use `new DateTime('@'.(610776000000/1000))`
not sure how you can handle the timezone. maybe the easy way just convert to UTC (by sub/add the seconds) its generall a good idea to only store UTC in the DB, and output as you need it.

Comment: @Rufines thanks, i've got the parsing to work just having problem persisting and flushing it

Comment: show your parseDate method, and the error you're getting.

Comment: got it all working now, thanks your comment helped me sort it out, i had a typo that was preventing the persist and flush.

Answer (score 0):

From Rufines comment i created a function to parse the date for me

```
    public function parseDate($dateString)
        {
            if ($dateString) {                    
                $match = preg_match( '/\/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d+)\)\//', $dateString, $date );        
                $timestamp = $date[1] / 1000;
                $operator  = $date[2];
                $hours     = $date[3] * 36; // Get the seconds
                $datetime = new \DateTime();        
                $datetime->setTimestamp( $timestamp );
                //deal with the offset
                $datetime->modify( $operator.$hours.' seconds' );
                $result = $datetime->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' )                
                //var_dump( $result );
                return ($result);
            }
            return(null);
        }
```